# Dry solder joints - what exactly happens?

Tags: soldering

[This Wikipedia article on soldering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering) and [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346442/what-makes-a-solder-joint-dull) explain basics of dry joints.

But none explain:

- why moving the contacts while the solder cools creates dry joints
- why the result creates poor physical and electrical properties
- to what degree, and in what way the joint is weakened in those respects

I am not asking about techniques etc, but for a deeper understanding that if necessary enables further reading. (This would be better asked on physics.SE except I'm only asking about electrical usage scenarios)

Comment: usually referred to as `cold solder joint`

Answer (score 5):

During the transition from liquid to solid, the solder must briefly be in an intermediate state. Kind of a slushy state where it is not solid, but also does not flow by itself. If the pin moves while the solder is in that state, then the motion of the part will create a hole or tunnel in the solder larger than the pin.

Then the solder solidifies fully.

So now you have a pin inside of a solder hole, with clearance all around it. Depending on whether it moves or how much it moves, it will come in and out of contact with the walls of the hole. In other words, it will have intermittent contact.

Depending on current and voltage through the pin, intermittent contact can lead to heating (due to high resistance) and electrical arcing (due to breaking circuit while current is flowing) which can lead to additional failures.

For a low-power, low-voltage logic connection, it can lead to intermittent erroneous behavior because the signal may not be in the logic state it is supposed to be in.